# Cannot remove Office 2010

Tags: windows, uninstall, microsoft-office-2010

Here is my problem:

I have a computer with Office 2010 installed in. However, I really hate this version of Office and I would like to install Office 2007 (which is, in my opinion, really better).

However, I cannot remove Office 2010 from my computer. I tried using the "Uninstall a program" tool of Windows, and it didn't work. I tried using CCleaner, but it didn't work too. The uninstaller didn't launch.

Have someone already encountered this problem?

Comment: What OS are you running? If you're running Windows 8, use [this Fix It tool](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9824112) from Microsoft to remove Office if you can't remove it form the Control Panel. If you're running any other version of Windows, use [this link](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9737366)

Comment: Also, please tell us what the error is when you uninstall but "it doesn't work". Just saying that it doesn't work isn't helpful. So many things can happen to make it fail. Do you have an error message, or can you describe the behavior you see in detail?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. Since the computer was having some other problems (mainly slowness), I decided to restoring it to its factory state.

Comment: It is a windows 7 and I wasn't able to launch the uninstaller. Each time I was clicking uninstall, nothing was happening (i waited for more than 10 minutes).